# fromEvent returns property does not exist on type 'Event'

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm trying to change an elements position according to the cursor's position. Therefore I have the following code:

```
this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
   fromEvent(window, 'mousemove').pipe(
     filter(() => this.hoveredCart !== -1),
   ).subscribe(({clientY}) => this.floatingElements.toArray()[this.hoveredCart].nativeElement
     .style.top = clientY);
});
```

Somehow it returns an error:

> Property 'clientY' does not exist on type 'Event'

Answer (score 1):

`fromEvent` uses a generic type so you can tell `TypeScript` what type it should expect:

```js
fromEvent<MouseEvent>(window, 'mousemove').pipe(
     filter(() => this.hoveredCart !== -1),
   ).subscribe(({clientY}) => this.floatingElements.toArray()[this.hoveredCart].nativeElement
     .style.top = clientY);
```